# Three.js unsigned byte attribute buffer

Tags: memory, three.js, webgl

Is it possible to use a Three.js BufferAttribute with unsigned bytes instead of floats?

I am rendering a point cloud using the [Potree library](http://potree.org/), which is based on Three.js, and I am looking for ways to save gpu memory. The library's binary format uses 3 * 4 bytes for each point's position, 4 * 1 byte for RGBA and 2 * 1 byte for the normal ([oct16 encoded](http://jcgt.org/published/0003/02/01/paper.pdf)), for a total of 18 bytes per point. The (perceived) problem is that the data is unpacked on the client side and everything is represented as a 32bit float, resulting in 36 bytes per point. Why not use the data without converting it to floats first? Is this a limitation of Three.js or an issue of Potree? And if the problem is on Three's side, are there good reasons behind it? (e.g. browser compatibility)

Coming from OpenGL and bare-bones WebGL programming, it seems really wasteful to use almost 2x more memory than needed...

Comment: Perfect timing. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8358.

Comment: @WestLangley Liking this! Looking forward to trying it out.

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks! Write it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @mihaib You can answer and accept your own answer. Do you mind doing that in this case? I have not yet had the opportunity to explore the new feature.